# 1996 Ford E350 5.8, Had difficulty starting, occasionally stalled at stop. Now cranks, but no spark, no fuel

Tags: ford, cranks-wont-run, e350

Heading says most of it. For a while I could get it started with starting fluid, and it would be ok for a few days. But now cranks, but no spark, no fuel. New fuel filter, I jumped the relay for fuel pump and it pumps up the rail. Remote (black) ICM new. Coil new. No voltage to fuel pump relay when ON or START. PIP signal OK. Fuel Pump Inertia switch OK. Any suggestions?
UPDATE! Somehow, I (or the fuse gremlin) moved the PCM fuse to the wrong slot in the underhood fuse box. It did have a bad ICM. That was only part of the problem. Still won't start at times, until I hit it with starting fluid. And of course when it doesn't, I don't have time to break out fuel gauge and check pressure

Comment: Solved! Somehow I (or the fuse gremlin) moved the PCM fuse to the wrong slot in the underhood fuse box. I did have a bad ICM, too. Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! If you would, please put the answer you posted in the comment into a regular answer below, then when capable, set as "the answer" by clicking the check mark :o) Glad you figured it out!